# MacBook Pro 8,1 triple boot, rEFIt not showing, Mac only boots on windows

Tags: macbook, multi-boot, boot-camp, mbr, refit

I'm new to Mac multi booting. I've just installed a triple boot (OS X Mountain Lion + Ubuntu 12.04 + Windows 7 Ultimate) on my MacBook Pro 8,1.

Everything went more or less right. I had the rEFIt menu showing up and all three OSes were just fine. Recently I updated Windows and when rebooting I lost rEFIt. Now when I power on my Mac I don't have rEFIt anymore, and it automatically boots into Windows.

Windows messed with my MBR, right? Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well eventually I came up with the solution.

So, one of the times I went to windows 7 to install updates and configure everything, i must have gone to the windows control panel and clicked on the Boot Camp icon to see what it was. And I must have messed with it and clicked on the Windows Partitition. When you click nothing happens but it stays **clicked** and that means windows (Boot Camp) will be the default boot partitition leaving rEFIt on the shadow :P

Not very clear information about this, and specially the control panel application if definitly not clear about when it's clicked or not.

Anyway, I hope it helps somebody. I spent a few unnecesseary hours after the solution.